# VLANS on Netplan break ping/ssh

Tags: networking, server, ssh, netplan, network-bonding

Took me a while to figure out correct format for Netplan to work properly with vlans. Anyway, this applies properly but breaks ping and ssh on both vlans. I would also rather only have the ip addresses on the vlan interfaces only and not the actual bond0 interface, is that possible?

```
network:
  bonds:
    bond0:
      addresses:
        - (ip addr of bond0)/27
      gateway4: (gw of bond 0)
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - (internal dns server 1)
          - (internal dns server 2)
      parameters:
        lacp-rate: slow
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2
  ethernets:
    eno1: {}
    eno2: {}
  version: 2
  vlans:
    bond0.6:
      id: 6
      link: bond0
      addresses: [ (ip addr of vlan 6)/27 ]
    bond0.12:
      id: 12
      link: bond0
      addresses: [ (ip addr of vlan 12)/24 ]
```

Comment: You haven't shown your netplan config here.  This is almost certainly a configuration error, there's nothing about netplan itself that would prevent services from working over vlans.

Comment: Its in the picture attached. Every time I add my config the web page reformats it?

Comment: Thanks. The provided config looks sensible and should not result in your vlan IPs being attached to the bond interface.  Was there a previous version of your config that did attach those IPs to bond0, without a reboot in between?  In certain cases, netplan will not remove existing configuration from interfaces on `netplan apply`.